# how can I specify schema validate in Spring 3 config file with <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller> element?

Tags: spring, jaxb

I choose to use Spring Jaxb2Marshaller to support JAXB in my project, but I cannot specify a schema file in element `oxm:jaxb2-marshaller`, I found only a contextPath property, nothing about schema.

Must I use the old Jaxb2Marshaller config style (using `beans:bean` element)?

Answer (score 3):

The class `Jaxb2Marshaller` has a schema property, try this sample of code.

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>my.package.ResponseObj</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Possibly include schema for validation -->
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:schema.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

**EDIT :**
I think that you can't specify an XML schema directly in the config file with the new OXM balise. There is no xml element or attribut for this in the [OXM XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd). But you can use the new @XmlSchema annotation directly in your "classe to bound". Look this [documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ea/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html).

Comment: thanks, your solution is pretty good but I want the oxm:jaxb2-marshaller config style, not the old fashion. I can not found any schema config property in oxm:jaxb2-marshaller element.